# Convert a decimalized number into a fraction of eighths

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fairly sure this is a simple problem, but I'm having issues wrapping my head around it. Suppose I have a decimalized number:

```
1.25
1.5
2.75
2.45
```

How do I convert the decimal part to be shown as a fraction of eighths? e.g.

```
1 2/8
1 4/8
2 6/8
2 3/8 // I need to round down rather than up when its not a simple conversion.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post your current conversion code?

Comment: what do you expect here **`2.45`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple function to calculate the fractions using only Math (no split) in vanilla Javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("number").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("number").value); // float
  var a = Math.abs(f); // absolute value
  var w = Math.floor(a); // whole number
  var r = a - w; // remainder
  var d = Math.floor(r / .125); // denominator

  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = f + " as a fraction: " + (f < 0 ? '-' : '') + w + ' ' + (d > 0 ? d + '/8' : '') + '<br>' + document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
})});
```

```html
Enter a number to convert to fractions of 1/8s.<br>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Lots of interesting approaches to addressing the problem, however I'm accepting this answer because it seems to be the simplest / requires the least amount of code :)

Comment: It doesn't quite work yet with negative numbers, but if you don't care for that then it's fine. Inputting `-59.12` will yield `-60 7/8`.

Comment: @timolawl Thanks for pointing out, script is fixed to deal with negative numbers as well.

Comment: Plus one, extracting the decimal part numerically is superior to using string parsing. Dividing by .125 is perhaps more intuitive than multiplying by 8 as I suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the decimal part (do that by taking the floating point 1-modulus or by subtracting the number truncated to an integer, taking extra care with negative numbers), and multiply it by 8. That then becomes the numerator for a fraction where the denominator is 8.

For example, 1.25 transforms to 1 and 0.25 * 8 "over eight", which is "1 and 2/8".

Answer (score 0):

Since `100 / 8 = 12.5` (and that is 1/8) you need to do some calculations to check how much your fraction part is (may be wrong, not tested in depth):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#num').change(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
    var parts = number.split('.');

    if (typeof parts[1] == 'undefined') {
      parts[1] = 0;
    }

    var fraction = parseInt((parts[1] + '00').substring(0, 2));

    if (fraction != 0) {
      fraction = Math.floor(fraction / 12.5); // 100 / 8

      $('span').text(parts[0] + ' ' + fraction + '/8');
    } else {
      $('span').text(parts[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num" /><span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Takes into account negative numbers, 0/8 fractions and zeros:

```js
var arr = [1.25, 1.5, 2.75, 2.45, 130.4576, 0.00, -0, 0, -1.5, -42, -59.12, -59.98, -60.01];
var decimal;
var numerator;
var output;

arr.forEach(function(number) {
  integer = number.toString().match(/^(-?\d*)\.?/).slice(1);
  decimal = number.toString().match(/\.\d*$/);
  numerator = Math.floor(decimal * 8);
  output = numerator ? integer + ' ' + numerator + '/8' : integer; 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', output + '<br>');
});
```